# Vision Framework Skipping Text Lines During Image Text Recognition in Xcode 15.0 beta 8

Tags: xcode, pdf

Text Recognition: Some Lines Skipped, Resulting in Inaccurate Output

I initially attempted to extract text from a PDF document using PDFKit. However, during development, I noticed that certain parts of the text were occasionally not being recognized and were missing. I also tried converting the PDF documents, but that did not resolve the issue.

Subsequently, I resorted to treating the text as an image for recognition because I didn't see any other viable options. I utilized Apple's Visio framework, but even it occasionally skips lines during recognition.

I experimented with resizing the image prior to recognition and attempted various filters (such as blurring, etc.) to enhance recognition quality. While this sometimes provided slight improvements, it was not a consistent solution.

Does anyone have insights or recommendations on how to address this issue?

I've created a test project to provide context on the issue I'm facing. This is to enable others to assess the situation and see if anyone has attempted a different approach that yielded better results.

It's hard for me to believe that the library is selectively recognizing parts of an image. Perhaps there's something I'm overlooking.

If anyone has any information or insights on this matter, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

https://github.com/SpaceGelato/PDFRecognizeByVisio

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhXBf.jpg)